# Best pattern to create a wrapper Constructor

Tags: java, oop

The problem is the following. Given a class `GenericConfig` which encapsulates a `Map<String, Object>` to contain several configurations, a class `SpecificConfig` is desired to have getters to retrieve specific map values.

For example, I want to avoid testing that `GenericConfig.getProperties().get(KEY_OF_PROPERTY);` is null and getting the value, with the burden of memorizing the key value in the calling method. I want to create a `SpecificConfig` that is created only if the key is present and that has a `getProperty()` method.

Example of what I want to avoid:

```
private final static String KEY_OF_PROPERTY = "key.for.my.value";

public void process(List<GenericConfig> configs) {
    for(GenericConfig config: configs) {
        String value = config.getProperties().get(KEY_OF_PROPERTY);
        if (value != null) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

This is my attempt:

```
public final class SpecificConfig extends GenericConfig {

    public SpecificConfig(GenericConfig from) {
        if(from.getProperties().get(KEY_OF_PROPERTY) != null) {
            this.properties = from.getProperties();
        } else {
            throw new ThisIsNotTheConfigIWant();
        }
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return (String) this.properties.get(KEY_OF_PROPERTY);
    }

}
```

So I can do the following:

```
public void process(List<GenericConfig> configs) {
    for(GenericConfig config: configs) {
        try {
            SpecificConfig c = new SpecificConfig(config);
            // now i can be sure that c is of the required type
            
            // do stuff related to that type
        } catch (ThisIsNotTheConfigIWant) { /* ignore this config */ }
    }
}
```

Is throwing a checked exception in the constructor a bad thing in OOP? Does a pattern to solve this problem exist? Is it viable to instantiate null in the constructor instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Why even have a `GenericConfig` as a class? All you want is a mapping `String` -> `Object`, that's just a `Function<String, Object>`. And I don't think your first for loop has an issue, if you want it shorter you can just `return configs.stream().map(c -> c.get(prop)).filterObjects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(null)`.

Comment: The information is available only in GenericConfig and it is an API from an external library. Such class may have also other fields rather than just a map. Maybe the example is a bit too simple. The generic concept I wanted to stress is that if it is okay to do that mess in the constructor

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When calling the constructor it *must* return an instance of the class, never null. But if you want it to be possible to be null, use a static factory method instead:

```
public SpecificConfig maybeCreateFrom(GenericConfig c) {
    if (<matches>) {
        return SpecificConfig(c);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then on the for-loop you can check for not-null. I think that is generally better than using clunky exceptions for control-flow handling. Though I suspect this is still not the best architecture for you.

Does the class `GenericConfig` holds a single config or a Map of configs? I would consider just creating methods to fetch configs with the existing keys + doing any null checks. Then you can just call `getConfigX()` or something.

Comment: That's an elegant solution. I agree that exceptions for control flow is a bad thing.